# Is algebraic notation unique?

Tags: notation

Can the same move be written two different ways that are both correct? In the following game when the black knight on g6 takes the pawn on e5, would it be "Ngxe5" or just "Nxe5" (since the knight on c6 can't capture due to the pin)? Or are both correct?

[image: two knights both attacking e5]

Comment: Do you mean algebraic notation as used by humans? Then there are many ways of ambiguity, there is already "long notation" and "short notation", and the letters for pieces are different in every language. If you mean for computers as in PGN, then I seem to recall it uses the "be strict in what you output, lenient in what you accept as input" approach.

Comment: @RemcoGerlich- Thanks for the response and insight. I am fairly new to the chess world and never really thought about different languages or heard of short notation and long notation! I ran into an issue in an online database I was using and it got me thinking if  something like this had a "correct" answer or if it was just preference of the reader/writer.